# What is the decimal value of the largest positive integer we can represent in 7 bits?

Tags: binary, decimal, converters

What is the decimal value of the largest positive integer we can represent in 7 bits?

My thinking is that it would be 1111111 = 127. Can anyone confirm my suspicions?

Comment: Is your 7-bit value signed or unsigned? Two's complement? Ones' complement? Signed magnitude? Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations for further information.

Answer (score 1):

The largest unsigned integer in 7 bits would be 2^7-1= 127. But signed integer will be 2^6-1=63.

Answer (score 0):

In two's-complement representation, positive numbers are simply represented as themselves, and negative numbers are represented by the two's complement of their absolute value;[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) the table on the right provides an example for N = 8. In general, negation (reversing the sign) is performed by taking the two's complement. This system is the most common method of representing signed integers on computers.[2]

[for more information go to this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)